# Unfamiilar macro expansion

Tags: c, macros

I am familiar with std #defines and macro expansion for min max function but this one throws me. In particular the #'s in the definition. Your thoughts appreciated.

```
#define TAB_WIDGET_ROW(t)     {t##_seq, t##_len, t##_rep}
```

Comment: It's called token-pasting.  Besides the gcc links that your have as answers, this one is from Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `##` is a C preprocessor standard macro used for concatenation.

This way, the code :

```
#define TAB_WIDGET_ROW(t)     {t##_seq, t##_len, t##_rep}

int foo[3] = TAB_WIDGET_ROW(bar);
```

Will expand to :

```
int foo[3] = {bar_seq, bar_len, bar_rep};
```

And the `foo` array will be filled with values of variables `bar_seq`, `bar_len` and `bar_rep`.

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) for more informations.

Comment: Thank  you both. Good explanations and good links too.

Comment: I am nitpicking, but: `##` is *not* GCC specific. Any C99 or C11 (or C++11 etc...) compiler should understand it likewise.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If we're nitpicking, then the compiler doesn't care; it's the preprocessor that does that. ;-) But yup... the idea that this is GCC-specific is not actually a nit at all, just a dangerously false statement. This is totally Standardised. I'd ask that this answer be fixed to reflect that. Besides, the OP didn't mention GCC, so if you though this was GCC-specific, the answer wouldn't necessarily be relevant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch & underscore_d : Thank you for the details, you were absolutely right, the answer has been updated !

Answer (score 2):

You should read some [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) concerning the [C Preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). The `##` is about [Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). So an invocation like `TAB_WIDGET_ROW(xy)` of your `TAB_WIDGET_ROW` macro would probably be expanded to `{xy_seq, xy_len, xy_rep}`

Comment: There also https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/447/preprocessor-and-macros/5494/token-pasting